# CodeIgniter on localhost : 404 not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes

For testing purpose, I copied all the code and DB records from our live server to a local server.

Our live server is redirecting `www.our-site.eu` to `www.our-site.eu/en` and then display the homepage with specific language.

The same code, same DB hosted locally, is totally failing. `localhost` is well redirected to `localhost/en`. But then an error 404 happend : `The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server.`

**system\core\CodeIgniter.php**

```
$EXT->_call_hook('pre_controller');
```

**application\config\hooks.php**

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
        ...
    );
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
        'class'    => 'MY_Lang',
        'function' => 'define_language',
        'filename' => 'MY_Lang.php',
        'filepath' => 'core',
        'params'   => array()
    );
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
        ...
    );
```

**application\core\MY_LANG.php**

```
...
header('Location: '.$config['base_url'].$index_page.$URI->uri_string); //http://localhost/en
exit;
...
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond $1 !^(themes)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|static|img|css|js|map|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|png)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/ico text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/rss+xml application/atom_xml text/javascript
```

My main config.php have to following line `$config['base_url']  = 'http://localhost/';`

I am pretty new to CodeIgniter, so I do not really know why it is working on the live server and not locally.

The `url_rewriting` is active on both servers.

Comment: Is the /en a specific route that's been setup? So /en is setup to direct to a specific controller? look in the routes.php file

Comment: @cfnerd I edited my post to add more information
ChristianD. No there is not specific route for /en but the hook for pre-controller is loaded before any route and redirect to /en. I do not really know how this is supposed to work